# Problem with key repeating when monitoring keypresses with pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I'm making this small program that plays a sound whenever a key has been pressed but, when I hold down any button it starts repeating the noise. What I want to know is how to make it so that when I hold down a key it plays the sound one time and does not repeat it.

```
def on_press(key):
    sound = random.choice(songlist)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
```

The problem is that it plays the sound while the button is down. But I don't know how to get around using that.

Comment: It seems like you could add a global boolean dictionary called something like `is_pressed` which is keyed by `key`, setting `is_pressed[ key ]` to `True` in the `on_press`  method. Then in the `on_release` method set it to `False`.  At the begining of the `on_press` method you then do a check to see if `is_pressed[ key ]` is `True`, and if so return out of the function,

Answer (score 2):

This is one soulution that I found, you can maybe get rid of one global var, but I din't think about it too much.

```
import pynput

keyboard = pynput.keyboard

active_key = None
active = False

def on_release(key):
    global active_key, active
    if active_key == key:
        active = False
        active_key = None

def on_press(key):
    global active_key, active
    active_key = key
    if not active:
        print(key)
        # play your sound here
    active = True

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listner:
    listner.join()
```